# How to return a array with first and last number exhcanged?

Tags: java, arrays

Hi i am learning java and really new to it..

Given an array of ints, swap the first and last elements in the array. Return the modified array

`swapEnds({1, 2, 3, 4}) → {4, 2, 3, 1}`

what i have done is this please help

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
if (nums.length > 1) {
  return new int[] {nums[nums.length-1], nums[0]};
  }
  else return nums;
}
```

i want to know what i should write ibetween ( "num.length-1" and "nums[0]" )

I know this may be simple for many of you but i just want to learn, so help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are asked to return the modified array, and not create a new one. Simply swap the first and last elements of the input array and return it.

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) 
{
    if (nums != null && nums.length > 1) {
        int temp = nums[0];
        nums[0] = nums[nums.length-1];
        nums[nums.length-1] = temp;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: There is no point of returning the array because the original array will be changed as well :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I only followed the text of the question - `Return the modified array`

Comment: Ya.. I got it.. The statement was actually meant for the OP in the context of your answer :)

Comment: There's no need for `if` ;)

Comment: @alfasin Only if you're sure the array is not empty. Otherwise you risk an exception.

Comment: Well, now that you added a null-check it makes such a sense :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it cannot be edited in place:

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
  int[] res = (int[])nums.clone();

  if (nums.length > 1) {
    int tmp = res[0];
    res[0] = res[res.length - 1];
    res[res.length - 1] = tmp;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Note that this only works for value types, since using `clone()`

If the original array should be edited instead:

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
  if (nums.length > 1) {
    int tmp = nums[0];
    nums[0] = nums[nums.length - 1];
    nums[nums.length - 1] = tmp;
  }

  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a temporary variable.

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
if (nums.length > 1) {
  int temp = nums[0];
  nums[0] = nums[nums.length - 1];
  nums[nums.length - 1] = temp;
  }
return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swapEnds(int[] arr) {
    swap(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a temporary variable in between to before swapping.

```
    if (nums.length > 1) {
        int tempInt = nums[nums.length - 1];
        nums[nums.length - 1] = nums[0];
        nums[0] = tempInt;
        return nums;
    }
```

Comment: You can change the code to check `length > 1` . `>0` will also consider length 1 and you swap the same the same element :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
  int[] myArray=new int[nums.length];
  int c=0;
  c=nums[0];
  nums[0]=nums[nums.length-1];
  nums[nums.length-1]=c;
  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {
     int res[]=new int [nums.length];
     if(nums.length>1) {
       for(int i=1; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
          res[i]=nums[i];
       }
       res[0]=nums[nums.length-1];
       res[res.length-1]=nums[0];
       return res;
     } else {
        return nums;
    }
  }
```